# Thread Safe Method

Tags: java, multithreading, singleton

I currently have a program implementing a Singleton design pattern:

```
public class Singleton {
    private static Singleton s;

    private Singleton(){

    }

    public static Singleton getInstance(){
        if(s == null){
            s = new Singleton();
        } 

        return s;
    }
}
```

I was asked in an interview that given a program like this, what are some good options to make the getInstance method thread safe. I know that one method is just to tag synchronized before the method, but the interviewer said there were other more efficient ways to deal with making methods thread safe.

Can anyone offer any ideas?

Comment: check http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern and check the code of Bill Pugh(without using enum that's the best)

Comment: It's all explained in [this excellent answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9239832/need-information-on-singleton-class-in-java/9239856#9239856) to a very similar question

Answer (score 1):

At least three I can think of, although two of those boil down to the same principle.

Basically you can either let the classloader worry about thread-safety or use double-checked locking from Java5 onwards.

The first versions means having an inner class/enum that contains the actual code, the second that you make the Singleton instance volatile and use the usual if-synchronize-if solution.

Answer (score 1):

Oh my word, not this again.

The very best way to write this is the simplest:

```
public class Singleton {
    private static Singleton s = new Singleton();
    // ...
}
```

Making the getter synchronized is the second best. There are a few more complex ways to do it, but none of them are worth the effort -- `synchronized` is *very* cheap, and don't let anyone tell you otherwise.

Comment: synchronized *can* be cheap in the right situation, but if the lock is contended it can get rather expensive.

Comment: If the lock is protecting instantiation of a singleton, real contention can happen at just one instant in time -- when the actual instantiation happens. After that it's all gravy.

Comment: But with your solution ("synchronize method") you synchronize every time the method is called, also after the instantiation. Which means if the lock is contended we get a heavy lock and some rather expensive locking.

Comment: The very best way is not to use the anti-pattern at all.

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline -- agree.

Comment: @user988052 A lock free collection would if anything increase the possibility of contention...

Comment: "I thought lock-free access to the head of each worker's queue head was made to reduce contention"  You never wrote lock-contention, there is a big difference between the two as you are aware

Answer (score 1):

**1.Create the instance variable at the time of class loading.**

*Pros:*

- Thread safety without synchronization
- Easy to implement

*Cons:*

- Early creation of a resource that might not be used in the application.
- The client application can’t pass any argument, so we can’t reuse it. For example, having a generic singleton class for database connection where client application supplies database server properties.

**2.Synchronize the getInstance() method**

*Pros:*

- Thread safety is guaranteed.
- Client application can pass parameters
- Lazy initialization achieved

*Cons:*

- Slow performance because of locking overhead.
- Unnecessary synchronization that is not required once the instance variable is initialized.

**3.Use synchronized block inside the if loop and volatile variable**

*Pros:*

- Thread safety is guaranteed
- Client application can pass arguments
- Lazy initialization achieved
- Synchronization overhead is minimal and applicable only for first few threads when the variable is null.

*Cons:*

- Extra if condition